# "Hashlib.HASH" object is not subscribtable

Tags: python, hashlib

I'm trying to make a code that takes a word and keeps adding characters until the last 4 of the sha-256 is "ffff".

I've tried using endswith() but I keep getting errors but now i'ts also getting errors. What should I change?

```
result=""
hash1=str(word)
hash2=""
while True:
  hash1=hash1+"a"
  hash2=hashlib.sha256 (hash1.encode("utf-8"))
  if hash2[-1]!= "c" and_hash2[2]!= "c" and hash2[-3]!= "c" and hash2[-4]!= "c":|
    break
result=hash2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the exact error you get

Comment: To get hash you should use this syntax: `hashlib.sha256(b"some string").hexdigest()`

Comment: @MotovYurii now when i use the "endswith()" command is says "builtin function or method " object has no attribute "endswith"

Comment: Because `hashlib.sha256(hash1.encode("utf-8"))` doesn't return string and it doesn't have this method. Try to use `hashlib.sha256(hash1.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()`

Comment: @MotovYurii Ok thank you it seems to be working, would you say that the code I wrote is an alright option for the goal? or will it take forever?

Comment: @BigBogBug It should take about 2^16 attempts

Comment: It can take quite a long time)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/) error message by **copying and pasting, starting from the line** that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` **until the end**, and formatting it the same way as the code.

Answer (score 0):

`sha256` returns a `HASH` object, not a string. You can use `.hexdigest()` to get a hex string, or just `.digest()` to get a binary string.

You can efficiently find if a binary string would end with some number of digits in hex:

```
result=""
hash1=str(word)
hash2=""
while True:
  hash1=hash1+"a"
  # add .digest() here
  hash2=hashlib.sha256 (hash1.encode("utf-8")).digest()
  if hash2.endswith(b"\xff\xff")
    break
result=hash2
```

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY9BysIwEIX3OcUQNwliwcIvIvQWLt2kZvInWJuSpFTP4qYL9U7uPYhNUl3MMPN4H_Pm9uyuQdt2HB99UKvt623OnXUBtPC6MTUhDn3fhIpSEqV1ZdquD4ynrYzyoE2DsHc97ghANqW-pIJOygKElFBI849-AkGjw9lYVvOZwmtR_m2AJbDA9mglMpoiUc5_8MQZldHJJP1ggmY1PVyUikV5jABQOxSnb_LkJp0zbWBZ4vnX-eXxPlgn8_wB)

Comment: I've now tried this but the result never has the sha.256 ending with ffff.

Comment: @BigBogBug What word are you using? It completes within a minute for me for most words I tried

Comment: I'ts a a random word, it's not that it doesn't do it fast enough but more that it doesn't get the right sha-256

Comment: How you you checking if it has the correct sha? It will have the right sha256 as you can see if you click the TIO link

Comment: wait but to make sure, do i need to replace the # line by anything?

Comment: No, see the "Try it online!" link, click that and you can see it work

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hashlib.sha256(hash1.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()` to get string hash.

```
result=""
hash1=str(word)
hash2=""
while not hash2.endswith("ffff"):
    hash1=hash1+"a"
    hash2=hashlib.sha256(hash1.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
result=hash2
```